# R: Change geom_text labels to color based on group with RColorBrewer Package

Tags: r, ggplot2, colorbrewer

I have a dataset that I am graphing using ggplot2. I have labeled the samples using geom_text and want to color them using RColorBrewer "Paired" so they are different colors. I tried this:

```
d <- data.frame(sample = seq(1, 100),  
                 score = runif(100,min=-1,max=1),  
                 day = runif(100,min=-25,max=100)) 

p <-ggplot(df, aes(x=Score,y=Day)) +
        geom_text(aes(label = sample, color="Paired"))
```

but I get all red color:

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you provide us with your data, code and all the stuff needed to reproduce your example?

Comment: Edited to add dataframe

Comment: Thanks. Please note that your code is not running, as there are few typos (e.g., calling `df` within `ggplot` rather than `d`, and some confusion between lower and upper case latters). Anyway, you want to plot samples in different colors. What do you mean? Should each observation has a unique color? Or do we have some categorical variable to partition units in two or more groups, each with a distinct color? In the latter case, Hugh Warden has already provided a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you are doing is saying to ggplot: "Please colour these dots according to the 'paired' value". As there is no 'paired' value it is assigning the same colour to each point as it can't differentiate. See example below on mtcars data:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = wt,
      y = mpg,
      colour = "Paired"
    )
  ) + 
  geom_point()
```

This will give this plot:
[image: Bad assignment]

Instead, put into the colour parameter of the aes asthetic the value you want to colour by. In my case I am going to factor the carb variable but you want to put in the value of your numbers.

Then you want to use the `scale_color_brewer` function to change your colour pallette. As your data is qualitative you want to add the parameter `type = "qual"`. Here is an example using the mtcars data set:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = wt,
      y = mpg,
      colour = factor(carb)
    )
  ) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_brewer(type = "qual")
```

Which results in this picture, where the dots are coloured according to their carb value:

[image: Good assignment]

You may want to experiment with leaving out the type parameter also.

I don't have your data, so I don't know if it would work, but I think your code should end up looking something like this:

```
p <-ggplot(df, aes(x=Score,y=Day)) +
        geom_text(aes(label = sample, color=sample)) +
        scale_color_brewer(type = "qual")
```

Comment: Hi Hugh. Thanks for responding. I got the following error: Warning: Error in : Continuous value supplied to discrete scale

Comment: That will be because your number values are being treated as continuous. Try putting `colour = factor(sample)` inside geom_text

Comment: You will also want to add `palette = "Paired"` to `scale_color_brewer' to get the correct palette.

Comment: You're more than welcome! Next time it would be really helpful to either change your problem to work on a data set available in R (like the mtcars data set I used) or supply a small data set in the question to help people try and reproduce your error so that they can fix it. If you feel I have answered your question please consider marking my answer as solved using the arrow on the left. Happy coding!